# Replace string of number / remove numbers

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, custom-options

I have create an **attribute** and it shows the **stock on our two stores**.

It is made through an integration from our Navision.

My output is `2.0000` etc.

I would like to make an replace on the stock number so I only get the number `2` shown insteed of the `2.0000`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're exactly looking for, but from what I understand, you want to get the stock value of your product and you remove number after poit, **i dont know why!** you can set the product quantity via admin panel. So to do your need you have to get your attribute then your add `(int)` in the output:

```
//get product stock quantity
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->joinField('qty',
                 'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                 'qty',
                 'product_id=entity_id',
                 '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                 'left');
foreach ($products as $product) {
  $p['products'][] = array(
        'id'        => $product->getId(),  //product Id
        'qty'       => $product->getQty(), //product Quantity
     );
  echo $product->getQty().'<br/>'; // 2.0000
  echo (int) $product->getQty().'<br/>'; // 2
 }
```

Comment: If you look here:
https://parkogfritid.dk/berkley-system-bag-xl-4-bokse.html
As you can see the stock in Aalborg is displayed as 9.0000 and in Brønderslev 0.0000.
I would like to remove all af the 9 so that it will only display 9 for the stock number and not 9.0000
There must be some kind of way to remove the .0000 af the number for the stock?